# Check if entry exists in previous mysql query results

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using MySQLdb with python.  I execute a SELECT query and store the results in a dictionary, D.  The actual query is quite complicated so it's not clear how to do it in a single query, which is why I'm splitting it into two.

Then I run a second query and would like to add the condition that rows from columnB in the second query exist IN D.values(). ie, I'd like to do something like:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect()
cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

cursor.execute("SELECT a, b FROM t1;")
results1 = cursor.fetchall()
```

## I'd like to do the following, somehow passing an array from a previous query's results into to SELECT command:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT c, d FROM t2 WHERE d IN results1.b.values();")
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can do what you want with a single query, and a join statement:

`cursor.execute("SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.c, t2.d FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.b = t2.d;")`

Comment: I should have  added (ill edit it) that I can't do it with a single query. The query is much more complicated than above. Well, I sure someone could do it in a single query, but it's too confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a set of values in an `IN` statement, but it is not advisable for the following reasons:

- Slow: An `IN` statement becomes an `OR a OR b OR etc` statement, which is just slow in execution
- An `IN` statement is limited in number of values you can place in there.

A better solution is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT c, d FROM t2 WHERE d IN (SELECT b FROM t1);
```

Or even better (faster) is the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT c, d FROM t2 
INNER JOIN t1 ON t2.d=t1.b;
```